# Wordpress Admin bar show only on Mobile

Tags: wordpress, admin

Hy,

I use the Admin bar only for Buddypress.
For the desktop version, I have all menu points in the sidebar outsourced.

However, the admin bar more suitable for the mobile version.

How could I solve it best, the Admin bar is only displayed for mobile.

Thanks for help. and sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: You want to display the WP Administration bar (to navigate to /wp-admin ) only on small screen sizes, and on larger screen sizes, you navigate to /wp-admin some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to implement a function such as the following:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'hide_admin_bar_prefs');
function hide_admin_bar_prefs() {
    $op = '
    <style type="text/css">
        html {margin-top: 0px !important;}
        #wpadminbar {display: none;}
        @media (max-width: 400px) {
            html {margin-top: 32px !important;}
            #wpadminbar {display: block;}
        }
    </style> ';
    echo $op;
}
```

Modified from the plugin Hide Admin Bar: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-bar/

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would add - you might want to check if the user is logged in or not, otherwise you might end up with 32px of empty space up top for users that are not logged in.

I just expanded it a bit - checking if user is logged in:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'hide_admin_bar_prefs');
function hide_admin_bar_prefs() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $op = '
        <style type="text/css">
            html {margin-top: 0px !important;}
            #wpadminbar {display: none;}
            @media (min-width: 992px) {
                html {margin-top: 32px !important;}
                #wpadminbar {display: block;}
            }
        </style> ';
        echo $op;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that might be a bit more elegant and doesn't require touching css.

Wordpress (since version 3.4.0) offers the functions wp_is_mobile(),wp_is_tablet(), wp_is_dektop() ([Wordpress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/)) with which you can query which view is currently available.
With these methods and the show_admin_bar() you can use the following code show the admin bar only in mobile view:

```
function remove_admin_bar() {
  if (wp_is_tablet() || wp_is_desktop()) {
    show_admin_bar(false);
  }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
```

Add this code to the functions.php of your wordpress theme and it should work.
Also use a child template so the next update wont delete your custom code.